# Chromedp Golang scraper not executing correctly

Tags: go, web-scraping, chromedp

I have created a Go module that uses chromedp to login and download some reports from my companies CRM system. I pulled this report on to our Ubuntu 20.04 server, created a bash file that enters the directory of the module and call the command:  go run.

If I ssh into the server and call the bash command on the file it executes as expected, I have this being execute by a CRON job and logging to a file in my selected directory. It is only logging the first output of the bash script and then it seems to be stuck after that.

**Here is an example of my bash file that is called by the cron job:**

```
cd ~/projects/DNC_Bot/dnc-bot
go run .
```

Here is an example of my line in the crontab:

```
30 7 * * 1-5 bash ~/projects/DNC_Bot/dnc-bot > ~/cronLogs/output.log 2>&1
```

I expect this to run the same as when I ssh into the server and call bash {bashfile} and it and it runs no problem, guidance on this is very appreciated!

Update to show code example:

```
func downloadLists() {
    // Adding options to run in head mode
    opts := append(chromedp.DefaultExecAllocatorOptions[:],
        // Change headless flag to false to see browser when executing
        chromedp.Flag("headless", true),
        // chromedp.UserDataDir(""),
    )

    allocCtx, cancel := chromedp.NewExecAllocator(context.Background(), opts...)
    defer cancel()

    // also set up a custom logger
    taskCtx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(allocCtx, chromedp.WithLogf(log.Printf))
    defer cancel()
    // Loop through Logics sites
    for entity, url := range logicSites {
        log.Printf("Entity: %s | Logging in to: %s\n", entity, url)
        // Log in and open up cases link list
        err := chromedp.Run(taskCtx,
            // Set Download Behavior/Directory
            page.SetDownloadBehavior(page.SetDownloadBehaviorBehaviorAllow).WithDownloadPath("./downloads/"),
            chromedp.Navigate(url),
            // wait for footer element is visible (ie, page is loaded)
            chromedp.WaitVisible(`#txtUsername2`, chromedp.ByID),
            // Login
            chromedp.SendKeys(`#txtUsername2`, BOT_USER, chromedp.ByID),
            chromedp.SendKeys(`#txtPassword2`, BOT_PASS, chromedp.ByID),
            chromedp.Click(`#btnLogin2`, chromedp.ByID),
            // Wait for Homepage to be viewable
            chromedp.WaitVisible(`#page-nav`, chromedp.ByID),
            // Click on Cases link
            chromedp.Click(`#page-tree > ul > li:nth-child(4)`, chromedp.ByQuery),
            chromedp.Sleep(1*time.Second),
            // Call func to download filtered views
            downloadFilters(),
        )
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? What errors are you getting? (that GOPATH setting is absolutely incorrect, and may be part of the problem)

Comment: It just initiates the scraping process, logs the first thing in the program to the output.log file and then stops. I don't see any errors with it. What should my GOPATH look like?

Comment: `GOPATH` must be user-writable and cannot be under `GOROOT` (which would be `/usr/local/go`). Just leave the default. You probably shouldn't be compiling and running this under `root` either. Without any actual code or debugging information, there's not much we're going to be able to do to help.

Comment: Ok got it, I have updated the question to show the script that is being called, and I updated the bash file to be just those 2 lines. This is still running fine if I bash the file manually but now when the cron job triggers it is logging this error: task.sh: line 2: go: command not found

Comment: Well you still need to add `/usr/local/go/bin` to your `PATH` to locate the `go` binary, or use the full path.

Comment: I updated the cron job line to use the full path to the binary: 32 16 * * 1-5 ~/go/bin/dnc-bot > ~/cronLogs/dncBot.log 2>&1    But this is still just logging the first output in my log file, from this line in the script: log.Printf("Entity: %s | Logging in to: %s\n", entity, url)    and then it stops.  I am thinking it's maybe a Chromedp issue? but I am not getting any errors

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if there is not a special reason, you should build your go app first and run the app directly. The advantage is that your app can run on a server that don't get Go installed.

I have just run the following demo as a cron job, and it works. You can try this demo first to check if there is anything wrong.

**Note**: check your system log (most of the time, it's `/var/log/syslog` to check if any error message is logged and make sure the cron job has been run).

Files:

```
├── bot.bash
├── go.mod
└── main.go
```

`bot.bash`:

```bash
cd ~/temp/q74482280
go run .
```

`go.mod`:

```
module m

go 1.19

require github.com/chromedp/chromedp v0.8.6

require (
    github.com/chromedp/cdproto v0.0.0-20220924210414-0e3390be1777 // indirect
    github.com/chromedp/sysutil v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/gobwas/httphead v0.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/gobwas/pool v0.2.1 // indirect
    github.com/gobwas/ws v1.1.0 // indirect
    github.com/josharian/intern v1.0.0 // indirect
    github.com/mailru/easyjson v0.7.7 // indirect
    golang.org/x/sys v0.0.0-20220928140112-f11e5e49a4ec // indirect
)
```

`main.go`:

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "log"

    "github.com/chromedp/chromedp"
)

func main() {
    log.Println("hello chromedp")
    ctx, cancel := chromedp.NewContext(context.Background(), chromedp.WithDebugf(log.Printf))
    defer cancel()

    if err := chromedp.Run(ctx, chromedp.Navigate("https://httpbin.org/status/200")); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    log.Println("goodbye chromedp")
}
```

cron job:

```
40 * * * * bash ~/temp/q74482280/bot.bash > ~/temp/q74482280/log.txt 2>&1
```

Comment: that WithDebugf(log.Printf) argument you have was very helpful! Looks like the program is stuck on the line: chromedp.WaitVisible(`#page-nav`, chromedp.ByID). This is the output I am getting repeating in my log file now: 2022/11/21 16:19:32 conn.go:128: -> {"id":81168,"sessionId":"DE14AAEC539C2E4F5420F15598342503","method":"DOM.querySelector","params":{"nodeId":9,"selector":"#page-nav"}}
2022/11/21 16:19:32 conn.go:91: <- {"id":81168,"result":{"nodeId":0},"sessionId":"DE14AAEC539C2E4F5420F15598342503"}                                            I am going to try to add a wait time instead

Comment: Try to understand how the page work and make sure the element `#page-nav` exists and is visible. Use [chromedp.OuterHTML](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#OuterHTML) to  dump the html or [chromedp.CaptureScreenshot](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/chromedp/chromedp#CaptureScreenshot) to capture a screenshot of the viewport.

Comment: The screenshot was the key to victory here! So the reason this was failing was that I needed to export my login credential environment variables in the task.sh file. This is working properly now thank you so much for that debugging guidance!